# Select Parent Entity where given set (parameter) is exact sub set of Parent's child set in ManyToMany relation in JPA Query

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

Let's say the Parent Entity is `Parent`. It has `ManyToMany` relation with child `Child`.

```
@Entity
public class Parent{
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="child_Id")
    private Set<Child> childs;
}
```

And Child,

```
@Entity
public class Child{
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "child_parent",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    Set<Parent> parents;
}
```

Suppose our parent entities are,

```
parent1 has child -> childA, childB, childC;
parent2 has child -> childB, childC;
parent3 has child -> childB, childC, childD;
parent4 has child -> childA, childC;
parent5 has child -> childA, childB, childC, childD;
```

Now I want to query all those parents which have `childA`, `childC` together. So, in that case, the parents will be `parent1`, `parent4` and `parent5`.
(parent2 and parent3 are not accepted because they do not have  `childA` and `childC` together)

My JPA Interface method signature.

```
List<Parent> findParentByChilds (@Param("childs") Set<Child> childs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using SQL

```sql
SELECT parent_id
FROM child_parent
WHERE child_id IN ('childA', 'childC')
GROUP BY parent_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT child_id) = 2
```

If a parent cannot have the same child twice (e.g. you have a unique key on `(parent_id, child_id)`, then you could remove `DISTINCT` from the `COUNT()` aggregate function.

It should be straightforward to translate that to JPQL, or you just use a native SQL query.